# how to test chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener functionality on a service constructor in angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, ts-jest

```
export class ChromeService {
  private newTabValue$ = new Subject<{ tabId: number; url: string }>();

  constructor() {
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId: number, changeInfo: TabChangeInfo, tab: Tab) => {
      if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        if (tab.url !== undefined) {
          this.newTabValue$.next({ tabId: tabId, url: tab.url });
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hi, I have an angular service using the chrome.tab api to detect the url change of the page, and I do not understand how I can test it. How can I create a test and provide values to changeInfo and tab, and make sure that `this.newTabValue$.next` is called with tabId and tab.url values?